# Assigning a value to a structs flexible array

Tags: c++, c

So I have a struct as follows:

```
typedef struct {
     ......
     char* filenames[];
}

int myFunction(char* filenames[]) {
     myStruct->filenames = filenames;
}
```

This is giving me an "invalid use of flexible array member" error. Why is this? I know that I can't malloc my structs array so I am not sure how I would even use it if I can't assign values to it.

Comment: Because `filenames` is the last member of the structure, a C compiler will allow you to mark it (as you have) as having 0 members. This means that you will have to allocate memory for it by over-allocating storage for the structure itself. That is, if you need one of these structures to have an array of 5 char*s, then you must malloc(sizeof myStruct + 5 * sizeof(char *)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `char** filenames`. `c++` doesn't accept variable length arrays.

See [example](http://ideone.com/b3BtI7).

As a suggestion, not an answer, use a `std::string`. Or if you need the container, `std::vector<std::string>`.